# "An error occurred querying a data source", form designed using InfoPath Designer

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I am getting the below error if I try to open an InfoPath form designed using InfoPath designer

> Warning
>
> An error occurred querying a data source. Click OK to resume filling out the form. You may want to check your form data for errors. HIDE ERROR DETAILS The database returns an error. An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. Log ID:5566

What could cause this?

Comment: are you using any Data Connection? If yes, remove unwanted data connections.

Comment: no i have proper data connections .

Comment: Go through the Rules that run on form load. Make sure they are proper and  querying  data sources properly.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have used `GetUserProfileByName` service and if SharePoint is in Claims based authentication. If so, you have to convert the `GetUserProfileByName` to `.udcx` file, edit it according to the Central Admin changes, upload it in Data connection library.